# JavaScript display array elements within certain time period

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, display

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and working on some exercises. I'm trying to create an exercise where customer review display once the page loads one at a time 5 seconds each. The reviews are each an object array element. So I'm trying to figure out how to loop through the object array and display each element 5 seconds each. I've done some research and this is all I could come up with. Am I even close?

```html
<script>
  var customerReviews = {
    "Denise Wilson": [
      "I absolutely love this restaurant! The food is amazing. The atmosphere
      is so welcoming."
    ],
    "Russell Brown": [
      "Enid's restaurant is the best place in town. Great food, nice staff
      and
      very clean spot."
    ],
    "Dana Evans": [
      "Came here for the 1st time and must say I'm impressed. Will definitely
      be coming back. Enjoyed myself."
    ],
    "Bilal Scott": [
      "Been coming here since I was a child. Loved it then and still love it
      now. The best!"
    ]
  };

  function showCustomerReviews(){
    for (i = 0; i < userWord.length; i++){
      setTimeout(function () { .show(customerReviews[i]); }, 5000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body onload="showCustomerReviews()">
  <div id="reviewsPage">
    <h2>Check out Enid's Restaurant Customer Reviews below</h2>
    <div id="reviewsBox">
      <p>Enid's Customer Reviews</p>
      <p id="displayReviews"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have a bunch of issues with your code.You have the infanous for loop bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example, you have it where all the timeouts will execute at exactly 5 seconds, and you have a bug with whatever `.show()` is

Comment: You have line breaks between your quoted strings, is your actual code like that? This will give you a syntax error (invalid or unexpected token). I have fixed your code formatting but left that error as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want something to occur at a set interval, `setInterval` is a better alternative to `setTimeout`. You can just start it and let it run without the problems associated with timeouts in `for` loops.

Here I've changed your code a bit to make `customerReviews` a real array containing review objects that have the name of the reviewer and the review itself as properties. Then it's a simple matter of running `setInterval()` and incrementing the index. To make it loop, this takes the index mod `%` `array.length`

If you want to stop it you can use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

```js
var customerReviews = [
    {   
        name: "Denise Wilson",
        review:"I absolutely love this restaurant! The food is amazing. The atmosphere is so welcoming."
    },
    {   
        name: "Russell Brown",
        review: "Enid's restaurant is the best place in town. Great food, nice staff and very clean spot."
    },
    { 
        name: "Dana Evans",
        review: "Came here for the 1st time and must say I'm impressed. Will definitely be coming back. Enjoyed myself."
    },
    {   
        name: "Bilal Scott",
        review: "Been coming here since I was a child. Loved it then and still love it now. The best!"
    }
];


function showCustomerReviews(){
      let i = 0
      // set initial review
      let review = customerReviews[i++ % customerReviews.length]
      $('#displayReviews').text(review.name + ": " + review.review);
      
      // change it on interval
      setInterval(function(){
        let review = customerReviews[i++ % customerReviews.length]
        $('#displayReviews').text(review.name + ": " + review.review);
        }, 5000);
    }
showCustomerReviews()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reviewsPage">
<h2>Check out Enid's Restaurant Customer Reviews below</h2>
<div id="reviewsBox">
<p>Enid's Customer Reviews</p>
<p id="displayReviews"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer and thank you for the example.  I needed something similar and ran across this and it is an outstanding solution.  BTW, nice use of the modulus operator to control the array index!